# send http:// URL to UIDocumentInteractionController objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios7, instagram, ios7.1, uidocumentinteraction

I use UIDocumentInteractionController to share local saved image to Instagram.
by that:

```
NSString *writePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instagram.igo"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:writePath];
self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
```

But I need to share image which is on the server, URL link not filewith

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-4.jpg"];
self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
```

when I do that I face this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme http.  Only the file scheme is supported.'
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Thank you,